Using Indy HTTP under C++Builder to download file located behind a proxy
I am blocked in my attempt to download a file via a proxy using TIdHTTP. An exception EIdHTTPProtocolException is raised with the simple message error '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>' which corresponds to the first line of the file to be download.
The download works fine when I use the URLs directly in browsers, meaning via proxy or not.
Below are snippets of my code. Any idea to help ?
// Client side : C++Builder code ...
 TIdHTTP *IdHTTP1 = new TIdHTTP(this); TFileStream *FileStream1;
 try {FileStream1 = new TFileStream(myTempFileOnDisk, fmCreate);
      TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL *LHandler = new TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL(this);
      IdHTTP1->IOHandler = LHandler;
      IdHTTP1->HandleRedirects = true;

      IdHTTP1->Request->BasicAuthentication = true;
      IdHTTP1->Request->Username = "myUserName";
      IdHTTP1->Request->Password = "myBase64EncodedPassword";

      IdHTTP1->Request->UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0";
      //IdHTTP1->Get("https://www.myurl.com/myFileFolder/myFileToDownload.xml", FileStream1); // => Works fine !
      IdHTTP1->Request->ContentType = "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
      IdHTTP1->Get("https://www.myurl.com/myProxy.php", FileStream1); // => Error

      myBoxMessage = "Success!";
      if(IdHTTP1->ResponseCode != 200) myBoxMessage = "Failure : "+ IdHTTP1->ResponseText +".";
      LHandler->Free();
     }
 catch(EIdHTTPProtocolException &EX0Vl) {myLogMessage = EX0Vl.Message; myLogFunction();}
 catch(EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid &EX0Vl) {myLogMessage = EX0Vl.Message; myLogFunction();}
 catch(...) {myLogMessage = "Exception non planifiée."; myLogFunction();}

 FileStream1->Free();

// Server side : PHP code = proxy ...
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "myBase64EncodedPassword")
    {try {$filename = (true)?"myFileToDownload.xml":"myFileToDownload.xlsx";
          $filepath = 'https://www.myurl.com/myFileFolder/'. $filename;
          if(fopen($filepath, 'r'))
            {header('Pragma: public');
             //header('Content-type: application/zip');
             header('Content-type: text/xml');
             //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8');
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $filename);
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
             header('Location: '. $filepath);
             header('Expires: 0'); 
             ob_clean(); flush();
             readfile($filepath);
             exit;
            } 
          else 
            {header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
             error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').", myProxy : File not found".PHP_EOL, 3, './myLogFile.log');   
             exit("File not found");
            }
         } 
     catch (Exception $EX0) 
        {header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
         error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').", myProxy : Internal Server Error".PHP_EOL, 3, './myLogFile.log');
         exit("Internal Server Error");
        }
    }   

// XML File
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ArticleTable xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</ArticleTable>


I updated my PHP code but the client is still raising the exception:
if ($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] == "myBase64EncodedPassword")
    {try {$filename = (true)?"myFileToDownload.xml":"myFileToDownload.xlsx";
          $filepath = 'https://www.myurl.com/myFileFolder/'. $filename;
          if(fopen($filepath, 'r'))
            {header('Pragma: public');
             //header('Content-type: application/zip');
             header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
             header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary');
             //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8');
             header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
             header('Content-Length: '. filesize($filename));
             header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $filename);
             header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
             header('Location: '. $filepath);
             header('Expires: 0'); 
             ob_clean(); flush();
             readfile($filepath);
             header('HTTP/1.1 200');
             exit(0);
            } 
          else 
            {header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not found');
             error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').", myProxy : File not found".PHP_EOL, 3, './myLogFile.log');   
             exit("File not found");
            }
         } 
     catch (Exception $EX0) 
        {header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
         error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s').", myProxy : Internal Server Error".PHP_EOL, 3, './myLogFile.log');
         exit("Internal Server Error");
        }
    } 


Finally got the solution by adding command IdHTTP1->ProtocolVersion = pv1_0;.

EIdHTTPProtocolException is raised when the HTTP server returns a non-success HTTP response code.
In your client code, you will never reach the if(IdHTTP1->ResponseCode != 200) statement if the Get() call fails, unless you enable the hoNoProtocolException flag in the TIdHTTP::HTTPOptions property.
If your PHP script opens the file successfully, it needs to send a 200 response code to the client. But the PHP code you have shown is not doing that. That has nothing to do with the ProtocolVersion which the client uses.

On a side note:
UTF-8 is not a valid value for the Content-Transfer-Encoding header. You should be putting that value in the charset attribute of the Content-Type header instead.
Also, do not include a Location header on a non-redirect response. If you want to include the location of the file (which is odd for a proxy to do), use the Content-Location header instead.
Also, in the client code you have shown, you will never get an EIdIOHandlerPropInvalid exception raised, so you can remove that catch block.

UPDATE: the 200 header you added is incomplete (it is missing OK after 200), but more importantly it is in the wrong place. It needs to be the 1st header sent before sending the file, not sent after the file as you have it now.
$handle = fopen($filepath, 'rb'); // open the file in binary mode
                                  // and save the handle for reading
if ($handle)
{
  header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); // <-- send the HTTP response code first!
  // then send other HTTP headers...
  // then read from $handle and send the data...
  fclose($handle); // and finally close the file
  exit(0);
}


Thank you so much for the above response @RemyLebeau. I Updated my post.

@ibouka You are not using the 200 header correctly. I have updated my answer.

I updated the PHP code. This should be a complete sample for future visitors. Thank you again @RemyLebeau.

@ibouka this is a Q&A site. You should not be editing your question with the fixes. That invalidates my answer, because now it refers to mistakes which are no longer present, which is not useful to future readers. I suggest you restore the original code so the  answer makes sense. You can post your own answer with the working solution, if you want.

Okay, @Remy. I put the the very first version of the PHP code + The erroneous http code 200.
